# Self Contained MVC Website

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, self-contained

I once read about a .net framework which allowed for an exe to house an entire website and server, so deploy was as easy as killing the exe and launching the new one.  I am looking for that framework or any other like that for the .net runtime. Does anyone know what self-contained webserver/sites solutions would be best? And has anyone used it in a production environment.

Comment: If the web application is small-scope enough and needs to be modified and you don't want the bulk of a traditional server.

Comment: I don't think IIS is too bulky. You can even install IIS on a Windows XP machine as part of Windows.

Comment: The bulk it twofold, its easy to leave yourself open to security exploits if you don't have it configured properly, and secondly how quickly can you take a web app and move it to an unconfigured computer

Answer (score 0):

What about XAMPP USB LITE? http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#646

Everything isn't within a single .exe, it is within a single folder, but it does run from a .exe (or two i can't remember).
I haven't used this in a production environment. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think I'm looking for as much a miniaturized web server as a self contained mini-server

Comment: What do you mean by self contained? everything in a single .exe?
if you don't want the miniaturized version you can install the full version and still use local paths. that way you have 1 folder with as many copys of the web server inside all in their own folder. then you stop and start the exe in the folder you want to use.

Comment: I mean that there is a main and in it you call webserver.Start() with all the files embedded in the assembly so that there is one exe for the entire web part.

Answer (score 0):

I've found one of the one's I've seen: http://webserver.codeplex.com/ although it looks like the activity has fallen off.